# OpenCV Face tracker in iPhone

Tags: iphone, opencv, face-detection

I want to make a face tracking application in iPhone.

Can any one help me how to use 
    **CvCapture * camera = cvCreateCameraCapture(CV_CAP_ANY);** in iPhone?

When I add this line in XCode4, I got the error **"_cvCreateCameraCapture", referenced from:**.

How can solve this error?

Thanks,

Chetan

Answer (score 1):

The latest OpenCV source from the SVN trunk supports video capture on iOS. Take a look at this [article](http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/) for a pre-compiled iOS framework and an example project.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, OpenCV camera capture API cannot be used in iOS apps. You have to create AVCaptureSession and setup video capturing pipeline in order to get video frames from iPhone camera device.